# What is Connection String for Salesforce(To connect salesforce from Trifacta)

Tags: integration

In one of my projects, from the database vendor, I got the request to provide salesforce details. They're requesting Connection String for salesforce. But I don't see any good article which suggests Database to Salesforce connection with **Connection String**.

Does anybody know what is connection string in this regards?

**Update**: Since I can see some of the votes for details, here are the details which I got -
Connection String  somewhat looking like - [Link](https://www.simba.com/products/Salesforce/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/sf/strings.htm)

Comment: Well they can't access the records directly, so I think you need to expose the data using an API. What are they looking for once they get the said "connection string"?

Comment: I have given the oAuth details with connected app setup. Connection string the example they given is - like How we connect the JDBC driver in java. That type of connection string they need.

Comment: Salesforce doesn't have a native JDBC interface (it's not a SQL database).

Comment: I told them, but they were saying they got already another salesforce instance connected. This is the reason I am searching for any doc/link which shows how Trifacta connected to salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce does not have a native JDBC or ODBC interface, so there's no standard or canonical answer to this question. It's dependent on which specific driver or middleware or what have you that this project's architecture has sitting between Trifacta and Salesforce.

Perhaps Trifacta has a standard way to manage such connections - I don't know, I've never worked with that product. In any case, however, the answer that you seek won't be found in Salesforce documentation or reference material, but in the documentation for either Trifacta or the additional third-party product you're using to provide a JDBC interface in front of Salesforce.

Comment: You were right. They had there own version.